# How do I create a lambda expression with unknown fields?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic, lambda

I want to dynamically build the lambda expression so that I can build a query with an unknown number of fields...how do I accomplish this?

I am looping through an object that contains all of the fields and values adding to the Where clause for each field...

```
searcher = searcher.Where(f => f.fieldName.Contains(fieldValue));
```

i.e. pseudo-code:

```
foreach(var field in fields){
    searcher = searcher.Where(f => field.name.Contains(field.value));
}
```

If I were living in the stone-age I'd pseudo-code it like this:

```
var first = true;
string query = " SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ";
foreach(var field in fields){
    if(first){
        query += field.name + " LIKE '%" + field.value + "%' ";
    }else{
        query += " AND " + field.name + " LIKE '%" + field.value + "%' ";
    }

    first = false;
}
```

Please tell me the stone-age isn't more powerful than current technology! ;-)

Comment: You need to build an expression tree.  This is not what EF is meant for; it's not particularly easy.

Comment: The stone-age is susceptible to sql injection ;)

Comment: You need to introduce a notion of a field that would have a getter and a setter function. Then you create a field for each propery of your class. Then you put all your fields into a list. Abstracting your objects with such list of fields allows you to run operations like querying, copying, comparing without knowing the structure of your object. All knowledge about it is going to be abstracted by fields.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I think EF left out a very important feature ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful.

```
searcher = fields.Aggregate(searcher, (current, field) => current.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(f.Value)));
```